# Icon, Resource, or Font for the Check Mark of a QAction

Tags: qt

When a checkable `QAction` (without an icon) is added to a `QMenu`, a check mark shows when it's checked. I've subclassed `QAction` to provide a tri-state system with checked, unchecked, and partially checked, but I would like my checked indicator to exactly match the built-in check mark, if possible. I just can't figured out where that built-in check mark comes from so that I can re-use or duplicate it. The check mark resource that I've used isn't very close, and there are other checked actions on the menu. I've looked at the `QAction` and `QMenu` code, but I don't see where this is drawn.

What I've experimented with in my custom icons is to use a typical check mark for the checked state, and use a blurred check mark for the `Qt::PartiallyChecked` state. I like the effect, but I would like my base check mark to be the same as the built-in one. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Incidentally, I had asked a separate question about how to do tri-state actions, and while that answer--using a `QWidgetAction`--worked well technically, I didn't care for the appearance and am going this route instead (so please don't refer me to that).

Comment: I'm afraid this is hardly possible or leads to an unsatisfying solution. Please, read [`QStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#details). Because same things may look different on distinct platforms, there is something like a "theme engine" in Qt. Thus, one system may use a character, another an icon, a third lacking the feature completely. However, for a platform dependent solution, you may have a look into the source code to find your answer. [**woboq.org**: /qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/) might be a good start for this.

Comment: I've always found QStyle to be a mess to try and wade through and ultimately not worth the effort, but I appreciate the reference. In this case, I've simply made my tri-state action also work as a dual-state action and used it in every case, so they all look the same.

Comment: I navigated a certain time through Qt doc. and woboq until I found the most promising links. Well, it was a little bit tedious and more tedious would be to look into all the plug-in sources. (That's why I stopped my efforts at that point and sent you the links.) I guess, your solution is all in all the better one considering also the development effort which had been necessary for "a small pretty effect" in look & feel.

Comment: My thoughts, too. The purist in me would like to use the style system if possible, but I also have an application to get working sooner rather than later. I appreciate the help.